# iscroll body scroll not working

Tags: jquery, html, iscroll4

I have used iscroll4 for using zoom purpose.

I have used following code:

```
var myScroll;
function loaded() {
        myScroll = new iScroll('wrapper', { zoom:true});
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', loaded, false);
```

But I am not able to scroll the site. I have tried lot of time to search. Please track me in right direction.

In mobile i couldn't view the page after this section.

Answer (score 0):

Remove this line and it should work fine,

```
document.addEventListener('touchmove', function (e) { e.preventDefault(); }, false);
```